# How to change foreign key in Entity Framework Core identity models?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

**The User Model**

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string Code { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<UserClaim> Claims { get; set; }
   
}
```

**UserClaim Model**

```
public class UserClaim: IdentityUserClaim<string>
{
    public string UserCode {get; set;} = null!;
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

**AppDbContext**

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<User>(b =>
            {
                b.HasAlternateKey(u => u.Code);
    
                // Each User can have many UserClaims
                b.HasMany(e => e.Claims)
                    .WithOne(e => e.User)
                    .HasPrincipalKey(u => u.Code)
                    .HasForeignKey(uc => uc.UserCode)
                    .IsRequired();
            });
    
            builder.Entity<UserClaim>(b =>
            {
                b.ToTable("UserClaims");
    
                b.Ignore("UserId");
            });
}
```

**Problem Definition**

I have 2 models User and UserClaims inheriting from IdentityUser and IdentityUserClaims. The IdentityUserClaims model had already defined `public virtual TKey UserId` as the foreign key. But I want to override it and add the UserCode as the foreign key. `b.Ignore("UserId");` gives The property UserClaims.UserId was first mapped explicitly and then ignored but the UserId is still there in the generated migrations.

As you can see in this migration snippet, UserId and UserCode are both included, and two foreign key entries are generated.

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "UserClaims",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    UserCode = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(30)", nullable: false),
                    UserId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                    ClaimType = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    ClaimValue = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_UserClaims", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_UserClaims_Users_UserCode",
                        column: x => x.UserCode,
                        principalTable: "Users",
                        principalColumn: "Code",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_UserClaims_Users_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "Users",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });
```

Is there any way to ignore, remove, or override the default UserId column from the Identity* entities?

Comment: First ask why? What you are doing is changing how people expect a database entity to act. I would strongly suggest you leave it as `Id`. Calling it `UserCode` suggests you are going to use it elsewhere which I also wouldn't recommend.